# Syntax error in SQL subquery

Tags: mysql, syntax

I am getting a syntax error can anybody tell me why?

```
SELECT  c.clientid, c.clientname, c.billingdate, 
      (SELECT TOP 1 previousbalance FROM invoice i 
          WHERE i.client = c.clientid ORDER BY i.invoiceid DESC) AS remaining 
FROM client c 
ORDER BY clientname
```

What the secondary select is doing is getting the latest record for that `clientid` in the invoice table.

The program - HediSQl

SQL

And here is the error:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 previousbalance FROM invoice i WHERE i.client = c.clientid ORDER BY i.invoicei' at line 1 */

Comment: Please show the syntax error here. and which SQL (MySQL, SQL Server etc)?

Comment: HediSQL is the program, SQL and here is the error `SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 previousbalance FROM invoice i WHERE i.client = c.clientid ORDER BY i.invoicei' at line 1 */`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just guessing but it might indicate that you should replace `TOP 1` with `LIMIT 1` or `WHERE ROWNUM < 2 LIMIT 1`. What kind of DB are you using?

Comment: This does not work? `SELECT  c.clientid, c.clientname, c.billingdate, (SELECT previousbalance FROM invoice i WHERE i.client = c.clientid ORDER BY i.invoiceid DESC LIMIT 1) AS remaining FROM client c ORDER BY clientname`

Comment: This should also work: `SELECT c.clientid, c.clientname, c.billingdate, remaining.previousbalance
FROM client c LEFT JOIN (SELECT i.client, previousbalance FROM invoice i GROUP BY i.client HAVING MAX(invoiceid)) remaining ON c.clientid = remaining.client ORDER BY c.clientname`. I also set up an SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29e80/10

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `LIMIT` instead `TOP` like this:

```
SELECT  c.clientid, c.clientname, c.billingdate, 
   (SELECT previousbalance FROM invoice i 
     WHERE i.client = c.clientid ORDER BY i.invoiceid DESC LIMIT 1) AS remaining 
FROM client c 
ORDER BY clientname
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07c0e/3)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you have will work in SQL Server. Your error message is from MySQL.

Try this:

```
SELECT c.clientid, 
       c.clientname, 
       c.billingdate, 
       (
       SELECT previousbalance 
       FROM invoice i 
       WHERE i.client = c.clientid 
       ORDER BY i.invoiceid DESC
       LIMIT 1  
       ) AS remaining 
FROM client c 
ORDER BY clientname
```